# Does my cat have an infection?

Tags: cats, health

Our neighbor's cat visited. It has already been there for about three weeks, and it has black stuff coming out of its nose and on the sides of its eyes. It started with only its eyes, so we thought it was only eye boogers since it's a purely white cat, and we've seen that a lot in white cats. Also, the neighbors didn't do anything about it. I'm not taking it to the vet yet, because it still doesn't seem like something big now that it's been for three weeks and the cat is acting normal. I may take it, though, if I discover it needs it. I'm thinking it may have something to do with the lack of sunlight maybe. The picture will be shown below in case I'm not clear enough.

Now the problem here is:

1. We cleaned around its eyes with Q-Tips, but it keeps coming back.
2. After around 3 weeks MY cat started getting it at the sides of its nose, which is really getting me concerned.

But if it was some kind of sickness and was contagious, why did my cat only catch it after 3 weeks? Can it somehow be contagious to people? What damage can it cause to the two cats? If I clean their noses (and eyes) with anti-bacterial soap (really carefully,) will it still come back? I'd most definitely appreciate the help, provided details of coarse.

The vet has been costing us a lot for some time, and it's getting on our nerves. If there are any home remedies to solve the problem I'd be working on the cats 24/7, I don't mind. I just hope to get the this done without having to pay much, although if it's necessary I may have to. I have no idea what this is and I'm starting to get worried.

For more information, the first cat to have it had it only on its eyes, and I'm starting to think it was only on one at first but not really sure. But then got it on the sides of its nose as well. My sister told me it had a somewhat of a fever (she isn't a veterinarian or the sort) every now and then, but she doesn't feel it any more. The two have diarrhea but not major. They are happy and acting normal, playing together like nothing's there. And finally the MOST important fact, I suspect my cat is pregnant--she started having this for two days now. Can this affect her?

[image]

Comment: "I suspect my cat is pregnant" Might be a good reason to go to a vet anyway

Comment: I know and that's why it's costing. Took her and the vet said it's too early to know, and recommended be to bring her in after at least three weeks.

Comment: if this is a picture of your cat i dont think you need to worry,just keep an eye on it and take her to a vet if it continues or starts to get a running nose or eyes(most cats have some eye gunk and dark secrtion in their nostrils from time to time so this might be normal).

Comment: That's the neighbors cat, my cat has less than that around her nose but  I can't remember her ever having it before. Maybe when she was a kitten only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my cat Trine.
As you can see, she has the same type of secretions in her nostrils, and she has no infection, so this is normal. Sometimes it is more, other times it is less.

What you should look for is if it is red (blood) or green/yellow (infection,) and if it is, you need to contact your vet for possible treatment.

It is the same with eye gunk. If it is yellow/green, you need to take your cat to a vet for treatment.
[image]

Comment: Yeah, thought so, but is it normal that it keeps returning? I just checked my cat and it seems it's not there anymore. But the white cat still has it, is it possible that the cat is simply not taking care of itself? And if so, am I supposed to clean it off with something or just let it be? I guess the cat may finally get annoyed by it and clean it?

Comment: it is how the cat gets rid of pollen and dust it  inhales it is only easier to see it on a white cat then it had been on a darker cat but it is there on all cats.it is the same in humans particles gets filtered out from the air and have to end up somwhere the cat will clean it off by itself.